# How to turn azure deployment warning modal "deployment environment in use" back on?

Tags: visual-studio, azure

When you deploy to an azure deployment from visual studio, there is, by default, a warning message if the deployment already exists.  The warning title is "deployment environment in use".  There is a checkbox to "do not show this message again", which means that it will deploy without a popup.

Some of my colleagues have clicked this checkbox, to their regret, and now no longer see this warning modal.  They were using that popup to double check that they were doing the right deployment and want the modal back.  Does anyone know how to turn this warning message back on?

Comment: If it can't be found in the UI then I suspect a registry entry. I actually don't deploy from VS and instead I use powershell as I found it was much quicker. Using powershell you can query the state of the slot beforehand and then decide whether to do a deployment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a registry setting. Open regedit.exe and navigate to:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio\11.0\Core and delete the key "PromptBeforeOverwritingExistingDeployment" or set it to "True".

[Edit] There is an easier way to do the same. Right click on the cloud project -> Properties -> Development tab -> "Prompt before deleting an existing deployment"

Comment: I'll get the guy with the issue to try these.